# Getting error while retrieving JSON response from twitter search

Tags: json, twitter, getjson

My code goes like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JSON</title>
</head>
<body>

     <!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
     <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function(){

            var obj = {
                init:function(){
                    this.url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.jsonp?q=tutspremium&callback=?"
                    this.fetch();
                },
                fetch:function(){
                    // console.log("inside fetch mthod");
                    $.getJSON(this.url,function(data){
                        console.log(data)
                    });
                }
            };

            obj.init();
        }());

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am getting an error in console, 
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.jsonp?q=tutspremium&callback=jQuery1111026038460177369416_1416224819787&_=1416224819788

Please point out what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to authenticate first.
Follow the instructions in https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search.

Twitter Api 1.1 needs athentication for searching.

best regards